# ruby code for displaying many images in a carousel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carousel

I ve to display over 30+ images in a carousel-twitter bootstrap. So ive written the code as mentioned over there. The code for displaying one image is as follows:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">  
    <div class="item active">
      <%= image_tag('1.JPG',:size => '600x400', :alt => "College Building") %>
    <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

The above html code is to display one image in carousel. Similarly for other images we have to write the same code again with the name of the other image. My question is this
how do we write the code in ruby for displaying multiple images. i ve tried using array like

```
# in controller
@image["1.jpg","2.jpg",...] 
@image.each do|n|

# in HTML page
<%=image_tag("n",:size => '600x400')%>
```

I m a beginner so please if possible explain the code.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your code is on the right track:

Controller:

```
# You have to assign the array to the @images variable
@images = [ "1.jpg", "2.jpg", ... ]
```

View:

```
<% @images.each do |n| %>

  <%

  # You have to use the `n` variable, not the literal
  # string "n" that you used in your sample code. Notice
  # the lack of quotes here:

  %>

  <%= image_tag( n, :size => '600x400' ) %> 

<% end %>
```

You might want to assign an array of hashes so that you can store additional information beyond the image file name, e.g.:

Controller:

```
@images = [

  { 'file' => "1.jpg", 'alt' => "College Building" },

  { 'file' => "2.jpg", 'alt' => "Something else" }

]
```

View:

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>

  <%= image_tag(

    image[ 'file' ], :size => '600x400', :alt => image[ 'alt' ]

  ) %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot. I used your method but unfortunately got this error "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" So i added "if@images" just before this <% @images.each do |image| %>

  <%= image_tag(

    image[ 'file' ], :size => '600x400', :alt => image[ 'alt' ]

  ) %>

<% end %> <%end%>. Now there is no any error but still the images are not displaying in carousel. Please look in to it..!!

Comment: Hmm, something must be off. Make sure you have the same variable name in both places, e.g. `@images`. You can put this in your view to make sure you have the right value: `<%= debug @images %>`. When you get to the point where that shows th correct value, the `each` should work.

Answer (score 0):

1. I usually load all the carousel pics in the assets/images folder with a 'c' letter ending for their name. (e.g towerc.jpg). Could load as many as you want.
2. Assume first image to be welcome.jpg (because usually is a combination image/text. at least in my case).
3. Load a variable (@pics in my case) with all the qualifying pics out of the folder)
4. go through array in view to display images.
5. Don't forget to play with height and width #'s (xxx, yyy)

   ```
   <!--  file names ending with c.(jpg,png,gif,jpeg) are carousel only-->
   <!--  welcome.jpg is first active file, usually something special.-->
   ```

   ```
       <div class="active item">
         <%= image_tag("welcome.jpg", :width=>"xxx", :height=>"yyy")%>
       </div>

       <% @pics.each do |photos| %>
           <div class="item">
             <%= image_tag(photos[18..photos.length], :width=>"xxx", :height=>"yyy")%>
           </div>          
       <% end %>

     </div>

     <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&saquo;</a>
     <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&aquo;</a>
   </div>
   ```

BTW, JMM solution should work, just trying to make the point that you should store the images in the assets/images folder and get them from there.